# Execute a .exe with arguments from VBA macro in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, parameter-passing, exe, execute

I want to write a VBA macro to execute the following DOS command (verified, works) by pressing a button in excel:

```
powershell.exe -command "Get-ADGroupMember -identity "Sec_Tc_RWaccess" -Recursive | Get-ADUser -Property userPrincipalName, Enabled| Select userPrincipalName, Enabled | Export-csv -path C:\temp\textfile.csv"
```

My idea was to use the function:

```
Shell (Program,WindowStyle)
```

but I don't manage to pass the arguments to *powershell.exe*

Comment: What did you try? Any quotes within the `Program` string need to be doubled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

**I would run something like this** (untested):

```
Sub test()
    Call Shell("powershell -command ""Get-ADGroupMember -identity ""Sec_Tc_RWaccess"" -Recursive | Get-ADUser -Property userPrincipalName, Enabled| Select userPrincipalName, Enabled | Export-csv -path C:\temp\textfile.csv""", vbMaximizedFocus)
End Sub
```

Please amend your question by including the exact code you are trying to run. That helps us (and other people who have the same problem) a lot.

Comment: thanks a lot. these double quotes solved my problem.